# WordPress php global interceptor

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add global interceptor to my WordPress application by using a following action:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'somefunc' );

function somefunc() {
    //do some logic
}
```

It is working fine only for front end pages and doesn't work in dashboard, for example this hook is not invoked for the following url:

http://example.com/wp-admin/profile.php

How to set this global hook for admin pages also ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `template_redirect` action is only fired on the front end of the site. Depending on when you want to execute your logic, there are a few different actions you can hook on to.

Usually it's fine just to hook on to [`init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) and fire your logic there:

```
add_action( 'init', 'somefunc' );

function somefunc() {
    //do some logic which executes on front end and admin.
}
```

If that's too early for your code then take a look at the list of actions and filters fired during a typical request and try a later one: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/

Answer (score 1):

Admin isnt using the template in the same way, so you need to add in an admin hook:

```
 add_action( 'admin_init', 'somefunc' );
```

[Wordpress Admin Hook Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init)